# Try-and-Increment method of ECC generator creation with Pycryptodome

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, pycrypto, pycryptodome

I am using the pycryptodome package to implement a cryptographic voting protocol. I am using the Nist256 curve and would like to create a second generator, independent of the default generator i.e. not related to it by scalar multiplication.

The common way to do this is by the try-and-increment method (if there is another method which works with pycryptodome then please tell) which involves basically:

1. Create some unique hash with context specific information and some padding. Treat this as the x coordinate of the generator.
2. Find the equivalent y coordinate of the point using the curve equation
3. If this point is on the curve, then bingo you've found a new generator.
   If this point is not on the curve, then increment the padding and go back to step 1.

The problem I have is that I cannot instantiate a pycryptodome EccPoint without knowledge of both the x and y coordinates. I cannot work out what the y coordinate is according to the curve equation because I cannot reproduce the curve equation with the parameters in the private EccCurve._curve attribute.

The _curve attribute contains p, b, order, the default generator and some other information. I cannot see how to reconstruct the curve equation from this information, is there a way to do this?

Perhaps there is a better way to go about doing this that I'm missing?
Or maybe it just isn't possible to create a second independent generator using pycryptodome?

Many thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably numerous packages that can do this, perhaps even pycryptodome. One relatively simple one this example uses is the [ECpy package](https://github.com/cslashm/ECPy). Here is an example that is inspired by my understanding of your requirements. It uses a method of an elliptic curve object called `y_recover(x)` that returns an int y if (x, y) is a point on the curve, otherwise it returns `None`.

```py
import hashlib

from ecpy.curves import Curve

curve = Curve.get_curve('secp256r1')
base_info = b'some fixed or domain-specific byte sequence'
padding = 0

num_new_points = 5
for i in range(num_new_points):
    while True:
        x_bytes = hashlib.sha256(base_info + padding.to_bytes(4, 'big')).digest()
        x = int.from_bytes(x_bytes, 'big') % curve.field
        y = curve.y_recover(x)
        padding += 1
        if y:
            print(f'({x}, {y}) is on the curve')
            break
```